# VBA Insert link in e-mail body without using HTML body?

Tags: vba, excel, email

I would like to insert a link inside the body of the e-mail I am creating through excel VBA. The link changes every day so I have put its value in cells B4. However, I do not find a proper way to send the e-mail with that link.

This is the code I am using :

```
Public Sub email_missing_forecast()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Déclaration des variables

derniereligne = Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row
Project_number = Cells(1, 2).Value
Project_name = Cells(2, 2).Value
Project_due = Cells(3, 2).Value
Link = Cells(4, 2).Value

Dim Objoutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim Objectmail

'Condition

For i = 6 To derniereligne

Adresse = Cells(i, "D").Value
Adresse2 = Cells(i, "E").Value
Adresse3 = Cells(i, "F").Value

If Cells(i, "B").Value = "No" Then
    Set Objoutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set Objectmail = Outlook.createitem(olmailitem)

        With Objectmail
        .To = Adresse & ";" & Adresse2 & ";" & Adresse3
        .Subject = "Bobbi Brown | " & Project_number & " " & Project_name & " | Forecast due " & Project_due
        .Body = "Dear All, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "I kindly remind you that forecasts for program " & Project_number & " " & Project_name & " are due " & Project_due & "." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please enter your forecast at this link below." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Link & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Best Regards," & Chr(10) & "Christian Chen"
        .Send

End With
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Your e-mails have been sent successfully", , "FIY"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: resp. What's the problem?

Comment: See e.g. [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/605342-adding-hyperlink-email-body-visual-basic-applications.html) or [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/creating-a-hyperlink-in-vba-when-sending-an-email/1bcfc62f-0455-4aae-abbf-eb60e6b65aa4).

Comment: @duDe There is no problem with the macro technically speaking. I just want to display the link differently

Comment: @dee yes but is there a way to do it wihtout HTML body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two possibilities IMHO:

> - the plain text Email: NO clickable link is possible
> - the HTML Email: clickable link is possible, well-formed HTML WITH `<body`> Tag is necessary!